# upgrade to infinspan 9.4, replicated cache stoped working

Tags: spring, infinispan, jgroups

upgraded infinispan to 9.4 from 7.2
using in spring.
data cached to hostA, When running hostB , nothing happens untill timeout exception.

problem is proabably jgroups config,
maybe tcpping.

any ideas ?

infinispan xml

```
<jgroups
    transport="org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport"
>
    <stack-file name="jgroup-stack" path="jgroup.xml"/>
</jgroups>
<cache-container
        name="cache"
        default-cache="local-cache"
        shutdown-hook="DEFAULT"
>
 <transport
            stack="jgroup-stack"
            cluster="clusterA@eVigilo"
            node-name="nodeA@eVigilo"
            machine="machineId@eVigilo"
            rack="rackId@eVigilo"
            site="siteId@eVigilo"
            remote-command-executor="infinispan-cached"
    />

    <jmx domain="domain-web" duplicate-domains="true"/>


    <local-cache name="local-cache" />
    <replicated-cache-configuration name="replicated-configuration">
        <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/> <!-- REPEATABLE_READ -->
        <transaction
            transaction-manager-lookup="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.GenericTransactionManagerLookup"
            locking="PESSIMISTIC"
            mode="FULL_XA"/>
        <state-transfer timeout="480000" chunk-size="1024" await-initial-transfer="true"/>
    </replicated-cache-configuration>


    <replicated-cache name="rep-cache" configuration="replicated-configuration" />
    <!--        <replicated-cache name="test-cache" configuration="replicated-configuration"></replicated-cache>-->
</cache-container>
```

jgroup xml

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/JGroups-4.0.xsd">

<TCP
        bind_addr="hostA"
        bind_port="8901"/>
<TCPPING
        initial_hosts="hostA,hostB"
        port_range="1"
        ergonomics="false"
/>
<MERGE3 max_interval="30000" min_interval="10000"/>
<FD_SOCK />
<FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3"/>
<VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"/>
<pbcast.NAKACK2
        use_mcast_xmit_req="false"
        use_mcast_xmit="false"
        max_rebroadcast_timeout="2000"
        discard_delivered_msgs="false"/>
<UNICAST3
        xmit_interval="5000"/>
<pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="500" desired_avg_gossip="5000" max_bytes="1m"/>
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false" join_timeout="3000" max_join_attempts="0"/>

<MFC max_credits="300k" min_threshold="0.20"/>
<FRAG2 frag_size="50k"/>

<RSVP timeout="60000" resend_interval="500" ack_on_delivery="false" />
```

hostB configed the same with bind_addr of hostB